# Cassandra : Replaced Node Shows In Nodetool GossipInfo And Nodetool Status

Tags: cassandra, nodetool, gossip

We are using Cassandra 3.9.0. Recently we had some trouble regarding 1 node. This node was crashed as 100% disk usage was reached.

One approach we are thinking to replace the node by a new node, according to following instruction provided by Datastax.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

After the replacement is done in a Test Env, when we do **nodetool status** from new node, the old node does not show up. But, when executed from other nodes, the old dead node shows up. Similarly, when **nodetool gossipinfo** is executed in existing nodes other than new incoming node, reference of the old node is found.

As shown below, we are replacing a2 by a4

```
Status=Up/Down
/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load  Tokens  Owns(effective)  Host ID  Rack
UN  x.x.x.a1  4.52 GiB   256      72.0%       HOSTID1  rack1
DN  x.x.x.a2  4.56 GiB   256      77.5%       null     rack1
UN  x.x.x.a3  4.33 GiB   256      76.9%       HOSTID3  rack1
UN  x.x.x.a4  5.59 GiB   256      73.6%       HOSTID4  rack1
```

When node tool status is run from new incoming node which is the replacement node, we get results as below.

```
UN  x.x.x.a1  4.52 GiB   256      100.0%    HOSTID1  rack1
UN  x.x.x.a3  4.33 GiB   256      100.0%    HOSTID3  rack1
UN  x.x.x.a4  5.59 GiB   256      100.0%    HOSTID4  rack1
```

Is there any recommended way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

That doc page outlines a process slightly different from the one I use to replace nodes, and doesn't seem to mention running either [`nodetool decommission`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsDecommission.html) or [`nodetool removenode`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRemoveNode.html). I don't want to make any assumptions about your cluster (for instance, you might be multi-DC), but I believe you will have to run one of those commands in order to have the cluster remove the dead node from the topology.

Since it sounds like you already terminated the instance that the "dead node" was running on, you won't be able to run `nodetool decommission` from it. Instead, I'd recommend going on another node, one that still sees it as part of the cluster, and running `nodetool removenode`. The command takes the UUID of the dead node as an argument, so you can find that via `nodetool status` to pass in.

The command is long-running so I recommend running it in a `screen` or `tmux` session. You can check the progress by running `nodetool removenode -- status`. The command will redistribute tokens that the dead node held ownership over to the other nodes in the cluster.

**EDIT** Just want to clarify that what I meant by the process outlined in the doc you posted being different from my own, I was referring specifically to running the new node with the `-Dcassandra.replace_address=address_of_dead_node` option. In any case, If the node is dead, and unable to rejoin the cluster, there's no harm in running `nodetool removenode` on its UUID.

Comment: It's worth checking `nodetool gossipinfo` before trying `nodetool removenode`. You may discover that the replacement node has the same UUID as the dead node, in which case `nodetool removenode` will fail with a helpful error telling you as much. 

If that's the case (your node is down, it doesn't exist, and a new node is using the UUID so it can't be removed) you may need to use an unsafe Assassinate operation. See here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751921/cassandra-host-in-cluster-with-null-id

Answer (score 0):

The other option you should have try that replace the same node if all good on that node. I meant own node replacement in this case no range movement for data and it will have same range and will stream the data from the other nodes according to the token range.