# Unable to load data into cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

In my Cassandra cluster of 30 nodes, having datacenter 1, replication factor 3.

We are facing issues when tried to load data into cassandra.

Error from log:

```
ERROR [pool-1-thread-8] 2022-09-23 16:44:29,430 CassandraLoader.java (line 392) Hector error while inserting
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace 'huawei' does not exist)

WARN [Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService-1] 2022-09-23 16:44:31,498 CassandraHostRetryService.java (line 217) Downed dmbas-r410-26(10.173.226.43):9160 host still appears to be down: Unable to open transport to dmbas-r410-26(10.173.226.43):9160 , java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

WARN [pool-1-thread-10] 2022-09-23 16:44:39,458 HConnectionManager.java (line 303) Exception:
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HTimedOutException: TimedOutException(acknowledged_by:1)
```

Can someone suggest how to fix these warnings and errors.

Thanks,

Comment: Does keyspace huawei exist?

Comment: I'm sure you've heard this before, but please build a plan to move off of Hector (Thrift).  Hector's repo hasn't had a PR in 8 years: https://github.com/hector-client/hector/blob/master/README

Comment: Not sure which version of Cassandra you're running, but if it's pre-3.0 you'll find steps on how to get rid of that old host here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751921/cassandra-host-in-cluster-with-null-id/35756401#35756401

Comment: @AsadAwadia keyspace exists.

Comment: @Aaron we are using Cassandra 2.4 version.

Comment: @user3051956 so there never was a version 2.4.  It would be either 2.0.4, 2.1.4, or 2.2.4.

Comment: @Aaron yes ,you are correct..it's 2.0.4